# appvue requires one element (vue2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

app.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="nav">
     <router-link :class="{active: $route.name === 'Home'}"  to="/">Home</router-link>
     <router-link :class="{active: $route.name === 'Cart'}" to="/cart">Cart</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$store.commit('updateCartFromLocalStorage')
  }
}
</script>
    
<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
    
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}
    
#nav {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
}
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgray;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
   
  &.active {
    color: #2c3e50;
  }
}
    
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js)
```

```
The template root requires exactly one element  vue/valid-template-root
```

How can I fix it? I tried adding more div but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are two roots in your component:

```html
<template>
  <div id="nav"> 1️⃣
    <router-link :class="{active: $route.name === 'Home'}"  to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link :class="{active: $route.name === 'Cart'}" to="/cart">Cart</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view/> 2️⃣
</template>
```

To create a single root, wrap the entire template in another element, such as a `div`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link :class="{active: $route.name === 'Home'}"  to="/">Home</router-link>
      <router-link :class="{active: $route.name === 'Cart'}" to="/cart">Cart</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That error is unrelated to the original problem. I recommend asking a new question so that someone familiar with the topic can provide a helpful answer. However, I beleive you'll be able to find the answer with a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one root level element for `vue2`

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
     <router-link :class="{active: $route.name === 'Home'}"  to="/">Home</router-link>
     <router-link :class="{active: $route.name === 'Cart'}" to="/cart">Cart</router-link>
  
  <router-view/>
</div>
</template>
```

Here `div` is root-level element.
However, if you are using `vue3`, you don't need one root level element.